# Why duplicate my rows? sql

Tags: sql-server

I have table Orders_Header, Order_Sequence, Orders_Samples with value.I want to get unique value from 3 tables:

I have one row in Orders_Header:

[image]

I have 2 rows in Orders_Sequence:
[image]

I have 4 rows in Orders_Samples:

[image]

My Sql Code are that:

```
SELECT orders_header.plant, 
       orders_header.shortyear, 
       orders_header.orderno, 
       orders_header.orderdate, 
       orders_header.closingdate, 
       orders_header.requester, 
       orders_header.projectnumber, 
       orders_header.costcenter, 
       orders_header.batchnumber, 
       orders_header.partname, 
       orders_header.partnumber, 
       orders_header.costcategory, 
       orders_header.status, 
       orders_header.overallproductrating, 
       orders_sequence.activitynumber, 
       orders_sequence.dimension, 
       orders_sequence.description, 
       orders_sequence.activityname, 
       orders_sequence.activityresource, 
       orders_sequence.requirementnom, 
       orders_sequence.requirementplus, 
       orders_sequence.requirementminus, 
       orders_sequence.units, 
       orders_samples.samplenumber, 
       orders_samples.samplevalue 
FROM   orders_header 
       INNER JOIN orders_sequence 
               ON orders_header.orderid = orders_sequence.orderid 
       INNER JOIN orders_samples 
               ON orders_samples.orderid = orders_sequence.orderid 
WHERE  ( orders_header.orderno = 79148 ) 
       AND ( orders_header.shortyear = 16 )
```

Why i get 8 rows istead of 4, i want unique rows. I have 4 rows in Orders_Samples i want in final 4 rows with all dates.

I try with distinct but doesn't work

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried putting a distinct in front of it?

Comment: Yes, but doesn't work

Comment: Each `INNER JOIN` on a table will multiply your results by the number of record hits for your join query. Your 2 rows in `Orders_Sequence` will multiply your 4 records from `Orders_Samples` by 2, resulting in 8 records. If you don't want that, your query on `Orders_Sequence` should be more selective so it'll only return 1 record.

Comment: @DenStudent A `DISTINCT` will not work since his initial query includes `Orders_Sequence.ActivityNumber` which seems to be unique.

Comment: The result doesn't contain any duplicate rows. You asked for the 4 sample rows with ID 371435 to match all sequence rows with the same ID. That's 4*2=8 results. A JOIN doesn't return only the first matching rows, it returns *all* rows that match the join condition

Comment: But how i do to get 4 rows, i want same numbers with results from Orders_Samples.

Comment: Without any proper insight to the logic inside your database structure this is not easy to answer. You could avoid selecting unique values from `Orders_Sequence` such as `Orders_Sequence.ActivityNumber` and add a `DISTINCT` to your query. Another option could be to add `WHERE Orders_Sequence.ActivityNumber = 1` in your select statement. All depends on how your tables are used and what you expect to get from `Orders_Sequence`.

Comment: Nop, is not correct, i want all rows from samples